# How can I prevent someone from altering or avoiding my JavaScript logic when adding buttons to jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, developer-tools, entitlements

I am using a jQuery UI dialog and [I am adding buttons to the dialog in JavaScript](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons) based on some entitlements logic. (I pass in a boolean from my server-side AJAX call if I am entitled and then I show different buttons based on that flag.)

What concerned me is what is preventing someone from using developer tools like Firebug and putting a breakpoint on that line that does the check and either altering the flag or dragging to skip over that entitlements check.

So my question is specific to adding buttons onto a jQuery UI dialog (because its not like you can add the buttons from the server side since its a jQuery plugin), but I guess it highlights a more general point around any entitlements logic on the client side being "vulnerable". So if there are any general best practices around this point I would be interested (but still looking for an answer to my specific example).

**NOTE:** I am also doing a server-side entitlement check on POST as a backup, so I am still "protected" but I am still concerned about the point above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing prevents people from altering client-side code, it is inevitable.

You can, however, add buttons of the kind of "server-side", you just retrieve a string using the AJAX call, which happens to be a JavaScript function that adds buttons. And on the client side do `eval()` on that string which will execute the retrieved JS function and will add the buttons. Moreover, you can transmit your entire JavaScript code that way, so the client cannot skip anything since all is being executed in the `eval()`.

A quick example:

Server-side function returns

```
string banana= "alert('test');";
return banana;
```

and client side does

```
eval(response.d);
```

Here is a theoretical example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/Gumvt/)

Comment: That's the right way to go. Do *not* store any entitlement logic on the client side, but instead check it on the server (based on the authentication data) and return the related UI-related code from the server. It doesn't make client-side manipulations impossible as Banana stated above, but at least hampers them.

Comment: indeed. technically, one can break after retrieving the string from the ajax call and temper with it before evaluating, but it makes it less worth the effort and people might just not bother.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot control what clients will do with your scripts, nor what requests they will make of your server. You must design your back-end API (not your JS client) to be the "gating mechanism" between the user and your system. It's best not to think of the JS as part of your system, but as a separate client that you ship as a reference implementation for your API.

But, if you wanted to at least make it difficult for users to mess with your code, you could minify and concatenate your JS scripts with something like [Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).

Comment: As i mentioned the bankend API does validate entitlments on the serverside but i also think it good to add this logic on the client side to give the user a more explicit experience (instead of making it look like they have the ability to do something and then click SAVE and it returns an error saying "You don't have permission to save")

Answer (score 1):

As the other person suggested, you cannot implement security on the client for exactly the reason you point out. You could use basic auth, or try setting up a token based approach.